# Getting downpress and constant coordinate for UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer

When the user presses down on a cell in my `UICollectionView`, I want to perform an action. This is easily done implementing the delegate

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didHighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}
```

however, I also want to get constant feedback for where the user's finger is on the screen. To do this, I was thinking about adding a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`. Does this make sense?

Comment: Do you want to move something around on the screen with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the doc [UILongPressGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) I would believe so. For this to work their finger would need to be touching the screen at all times though.  So to implement `UICollectionViewDelegate` method(s) for de/selecting an item in the collection view in addition to this gesture recognizer, would seem to be unnecessary.

> Long-press gestures are continuous. The gesture begins
>   (UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) when the number of allowable fingers
>   (numberOfTouchesRequired) have been pressed for the specified period
>   (minimumPressDuration) and the touches do not move beyond the
>   allowable range of movement (allowableMovement). The gesture
>   recognizer transitions to the Change state whenever a finger moves,
>   and it ends (UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) when any of the fingers
>   are lifted.